# enabled systemd unit does not start at boot

Tags: systemd

I’ve a `systemd-unit` on my system that is enabled. The problem is, it doesn't restart after a reboot. It depends on two other services that are both started as expected.

The service is known, enabled and dead:

```
[centos@ansible-kube-4 ~]$ sudo systemctl status flanneld
flanneld.service - Flanneld overlay address etcd agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/flanneld.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The unit file:

```
[centos@ansible-kube-4 ~]$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/flanneld.service
[Unit]
Description=Flanneld overlay address etcd agent
After=network.target
After=etcd.service

[Service]
Type=notify
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/flanneld
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
ExecStart=/usr/bin/flanneld -etcd-endpoints=${FLANNEL_ETCD} -etcd-prefix=${FLANNEL_ETCD_KEY} $FLANNEL_OPTIONS
ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/flannel/mk-docker-opts.sh -k DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS -d /run/flannel/docker

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Update 1**

Output of dmesg:

```
$ dmesg | grep systemd
[    1.312165] systemd[1]: systemd 208 running in system mode. (+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ)
[    1.317238] systemd[1]: Detected virtualization 'kvm'.
[    1.319597] systemd[1]: Running in initial RAM disk.
[    1.323489] systemd[1]: No hostname configured.
[    1.324874] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <localhost>.
[    1.327570] systemd[1]: Initializing machine ID from KVM UUID.
[    1.389047] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a78bb152\x2de525\x2d4f0e\x2d961a\x2dbf6147ac7d3e.device...
[    1.394577] systemd[1]: Starting -.slice.
[    1.396820] systemd[1]: Created slice -.slice.
[    1.397990] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    1.400212] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    1.401503] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    1.403556] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    1.404756] systemd[1]: Starting Timers.
[    1.406834] systemd[1]: Reached target Timers.
[    1.408042] systemd[1]: Starting Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    1.410065] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    1.413402] systemd[1]: Starting Paths.
[    1.415399] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    1.416574] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    1.418894] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    1.420242] systemd[1]: Started dracut ask for additional cmdline parameters.
[    1.422150] systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...
[    1.424870] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    1.426124] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    1.429731] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    1.692884] systemd-udevd[213]: starting version 208
[    2.621300] systemd-journald[90]: Received SIGTERM
[    2.968711] systemd[1]: Successfully loaded SELinux policy in 274.569ms.
[    3.023076] systemd[1]: Relabelled /dev and /run in 20.031ms.
[    3.365195] systemd-udevd[382]: starting version 208
[    3.482910] systemd-journald[377]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
```

**Update 2**

Output of `chkconfig`:

```
sudo chkconfig

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Output of `systemctl list-dependencies flanneld`:

```
flanneld.service
├─system.slice
└─basic.target
  ├─microcode.service
  ├─rhel-autorelabel-mark.service
  ├─rhel-autorelabel.service
  ├─rhel-configure.service
  ├─rhel-dmesg.service
  ├─rhel-loadmodules.service
  ├─paths.target
  ├─slices.target
  │ ├─-.slice
  │ └─system.slice
  ├─sockets.target
  │ ├─dbus.socket
  │ ├─rpcbind.socket
  │ ├─systemd-initctl.socket
  │ ├─systemd-journald.socket
  │ ├─systemd-shutdownd.socket
  │ ├─systemd-udevd-control.socket
  │ └─systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
  ├─sysinit.target
  │ ├─dev-hugepages.mount
  │ ├─dev-mqueue.mount
  │ ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
  │ ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
  │ ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
  │ ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
  │ ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
  │ ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
  │ ├─systemd-binfmt.service
  │ ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
  │ ├─systemd-journald.service
  │ ├─systemd-modules-load.service
  │ ├─systemd-random-seed.service
  │ ├─systemd-sysctl.service
  │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  │ ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  │ ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
  │ ├─systemd-udevd.service
  │ ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
  │ ├─systemd-vconsole-setup.service
  │ ├─cryptsetup.target
  │ ├─local-fs.target
  │ │ ├─-.mount
  │ │ ├─rhel-import-state.service
  │ │ ├─rhel-readonly.service
  │ │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
  │ │ └─systemd-remount-fs.service
  │ └─swap.target
  └─timers.target
    └─systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The unit file was modified:

*Before:*

```
[Install]
RequiredBy=docker.service
```

*After:*

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that modification I did not reenable the Unit. Turned out that this is needed for systemd to reconfigure:

```
$ sudo systemctl reenable flanneld
rm '/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.requires/flanneld.service'
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/flanneld.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/flanneld.service'
```

Comment: I too found that this helped and I don't know why. Perhaps `reenable` corrected something I hadn't done or had botched and couldn't see because I wasn't squinting hard enough. Anyway, of two identical hosts on which I was configuring to make my service come up after reboot, one worked and the other did not until I did this to it.

Comment: Is it possible it got disabled by an upgrade?  I had one suspicious server where it was disabled after an upgrade... **sudo systemctl reenable rails-puma.service** solved the issue

Comment: maybe relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193714/generic-methodology-to-debug-ordering-cycles-in-systemd

Answer (score 9):

I find no evidence in your configuration that this service should be started at boot time. `systemd` allows two ways of enabling a service so it is started at boot time:

```
chkconfig flanneld on
```

Or:

```
systemctl enable flanneld
```

In fact, the first is a legacy way of calling the second one, and I'm not sure if the `chkconfig` package is installed by default, but you can install it using `apt-get` or `yum`.

Comment: The service is enabled. I used `sudo systemctl enable flanneld` to enable it.

Comment: After running it it still doesn't get started at startup?

Comment: I have to start the service manually after each reboot. It starts on first try and without any error messages or warnings.

Comment: There must be something else failing. Officially, the way to enable a service on startup in systemd is `systemctl enable servicename`. Most examples also include the `.service` termination in the command, but I'm not sure this should do any difference.

Comment: The .service suffix is automatically added when it is omitted by the user.

Comment: I would do a `dmesg` or `journalctl -xn`, or at least press a key during boot to see if there's some sort of output.

Comment: @mrg2k8 I've added the output of dmesg. journalctl doesn't tell me anything related to this service. The machine is virtualized using OpenStack. I can't press the keys during boot.

Comment: What is the output for `chkconfig | grep flanneld`?

Comment: @nKn The output of chkconfig is useless. I added it anyway together with the output of `systemctl list-dependencies flanneld`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as described. In my case, with Ubuntu 19.10.

The problem was (I think) a bug in `systemctl enable <service>`. It created a symlink in:

```
/etc/systemd/system/mutli-user.target.wants
```

instead of:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
```

Simply copying the link to the correct location solved my problem.